# how to pass values between tabs in a html page using php

Tags: php, html, css, tabs

how can I pass values/ variables between tabs in html using php

I have 3 tabs those are fetched from database. each tab has separate id.

```
 <div class="tab-nav">
     <?php while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) : ?>
     <a href="vacancies.php?id=<?php $row1['id']; ?>" class="active"><?php $row1['name']; ?></a>
     <?php endwhile ?>
 </div>
```

**tabs**

```
<div class="tab-holder">
    <div class="tab">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="34%">Job Title</th>
                    <th width="15%">Experience</th>
                    <th width="29%">Location</th>
                    <th width="8%">Salary</th>
                    <th width="7%"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $cat = $row['cat'];
                if ($cat =='6') {
                    $jobtitle = $row['vVacjobtitle'];
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="pill medium green"><?php echo $row['vVacjobtitle'] ?></span>

                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['experience'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['vVacLocation'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['salary'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="post_resume.php?c=<?php echo $jobtitle; ?>">Apply</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php 
                }
           } ?>
           </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

how can i get id when clicking the tab

if ($cat == 6)

i want to place id in the place of 6

Thanks in advance .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're passing the value of `id` as a GET parameter, so you can access it by `$_GET['id']` in your PHP code

Comment: i tried it .href is not working. if i give any other page " <a href="apply.php">Programmer</a>   " it is not going . it is still in vacancies.php. i cant pass variables through href

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap for these tabs?

Comment: There's probably some javascript code `event.preventDefault()` that's stopping you from navigating to the new page